# Forwarding all traffic to other server with iptables

Tags: linux, iptables, nat, traffic

Assume I have a sever with X.X.X.X IP address and a web server with Y.Y.Y.Y IP address. How would I forward web traffic from X.X.X.X to Y.Y.Y.Y using iptables?

My servers run Linux and use iptables

Answer (score 2):

Enable forwarding and tell iptable to forward. Assuming you are working on port 80 then the following:

Enable port forwarding

`# echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`

Tell iptable your forwarding rules

`# iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination Y.Y.Y.Y:80`

[Source](http://www.debuntu.org/how-to-redirecting-network-traffic-to-a-new-ip-using-iptables/)

Comment: not worked i test it before

Comment: What response do you get?